# Java Math random() to print only one number

Tags: java, math, random

How could i get this code to just give me ONE number between 0-9.

At the moment it prints 10 numbers between that 0-9 but i need it to just pick one number from 0-9

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class random {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int max = 9;
        int min = 0;
        int range = max - min + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
            System.out.println(rand);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the loop?

Comment: You are probably lacking basic knowledge about cycles (loops) in programming languages, check this: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-for-loop

Answer (score 2):

Your `System.out.println(rand)` is inside the *for* loop that repeats 9 times. If you want a single value to be displayed, just remove the loop. That should fix it. Like the following:

```
public class random {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int max = 9;
        int min = 0;
        int range = max - min + 1;

        int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
        System.out.println(rand);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to remove it from the for loop but it gave me this error when i try to run it:

Comment: .java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(rand);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable rand